# Google Custom Search JSON API webpages only

Tags: google-api, google-custom-search

I am building a search component that allows users to filter by type of response. You can see all responses, just the PDFs, or just the webpages. I have the first two parts down, all responses is a basic search and you can filter for pdfs using `&fileType=pdf` in the query, but i'm not sure how to **exclude** the pdfs and only return web pages.

I can't find a similar "exclude" param such as `-fileType` which seems to be supported in other similar APIs. Maybe I just need to format the URL the right way... If anyone has insight into how to accomplish something like this I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with **-inurl:pdf** in your URL.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! Unfortunately I want **NOT** pdfs, or ONLY regular webpages

Comment: This is meant for excluding pdfs. "**-**" should do the trick.